# prevent an application to be show in the cmd tab (application cycle)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am developping a cocoa application and I would like to prevent it to appear in the list when doing cmd+tab

Do you have any pointer to achiev this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: yes (for preferences) but it needs to have an icon in the Dock;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an icon in Dock and not showing up on the Cmd-Tab switcher. There's no such public option is available, see `LSUIElement` and `LSUIPresentationMode` in  [Info.plist key reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW1).

One way out is to set `LSUIElement` to `1` so that it disappears from both the Dock and the Switcher. You can still have preferences accessible from the upper right corner of the main menu bar, by using [`NSStatusItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/Tasks/creatingitems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000996-BBCDAGHB).

Or, Cmd-Tab is controlled by Dock, so you can inject code into the Dock and modify its behavior, if you really must. Good luck!